# Power Automate, "Filter Query" in Get Items to get Date = Today

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to use "Filter Query" to filter my "Get Items" so it only returns the items created today.

Here is what I am trying, "Modified" is the column of my dates.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get this?

Comment: As I can see, you typed the filter right into the "Filter Query" field. Try to use that code as an Expression. Once that's done, you'll see the formulas are shown in pink.

If that is not the issue, could you please elaborate a little bit more? Do you receive any error message, for instance?

Comment: to clarify, what do you mean use the code as an expression?

Comment: When you specify some value, you are able to choose from the Dynamic Content box, but you can also click on the "Expression" tab (on the right side) and specify formulas as in Excel.